# Can I stop Angular.js’s json filter from excluding properties that start with $?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-filter

Angular.js has a handy built-in filter, [`json`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/json), which displays JavaScript objects as nicely formatted JSON.

However, it seems to filter out object properties that begin with `$` by default:

#### Template:

```
<pre>{{ {'name':'value', 'special':'yes', '$reallyspecial':'Er...'} | json }}</pre>
```

#### Displayed:

```
{
  "name": "value",
  "special": "yes"
}
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/oem4HJ9utZMYGVbPkT6N?p=preview

Can I make properties beginning with `$` be displayed like other properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you can't. It is "hard-coded" into the filter's behaviour.
Nonetheless, it is quite easy to build a custom JSON filter that behaves identically with the Angular's one but not filtering out properties starting with '$'.

<sub>(Scroll further down for sample code and a **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/6QSZ7/)**.)</sub>

---

If you take a look at the **[1.2.15 version source code](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular.js)**, you will find out that the `json` filter is defined like this:

```
function jsonFilter() {
  return function(object) {
    return toJson(object, true);
  };
}
```

So, it uses the `toJson()` function (the second parameter (`true`) means: *format my JSON nicely*).

---

So, our next stop is the `toJson()` function, that looks like this:

```
function toJson(obj, pretty) {
  if (typeof obj === 'undefined') return undefined;
  return JSON.stringify(obj, toJsonReplacer, pretty ? '  ' : null);
}
```

This function makes use of the "native" **[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** function, passing a custom replacer function (`toJsonReplacer`).

---

The `toJsonReplacer()` function handles some special cases: It checks if the key starts with `$` and ignores it if it does (this is what we want to change) and it checks if the value is either a Window, a Document or a Scope object (in which case it converts it to a descriptive string in order to avoid "Converting circular structure to JSON" errors).

```
function toJsonReplacer(key, value) {
  var val = value;

  if (typeof key === 'string' && key.charAt(0) === '$') {
    val = undefined;
  } else if (isWindow(value)) {
    val = '$WINDOW';
  } else if (value &&  document === value) {
    val = '$DOCUMENT';
  } else if (isScope(value)) {
    val = '$SCOPE';
  }

  return val;
}
```

---

For the sake of completeness, the two functions that check for Window and Scope look like this:

```
function isWindow(obj) {
  return obj && obj.document && obj.location && obj.alert && obj.setInterval;
}

function isScope(obj) {
  return obj && obj.$evalAsync && obj.$watch;
}
```

---

Finally, all we need to do is to create a custom filter that uses the exact same code, with the sole difference that our `toJsonReplacer()` won't filter out properties starting with `$`.

```
app.filter('customJson', function () {
    function isWindow(obj) {
        return obj && 
               obj.document && 
               obj.location && 
               obj.alert && 
               obj.setInterval;
    }

    function isScope(obj) {
        return obj && 
               obj.$evalAsync && 
               obj.$watch;
    }

    function toJsonReplacer(key, value) {
        var val = value;

        if (isWindow(value)) {
            val = '$WINDOW';
        } else if (value && (document === value)) {
            val = '$DOCUMENT';
        } else if (isScope(value)) {
            val = '$SCOPE';
        }

        return val;
    }

    function toJson(obj, pretty) {
        if (typeof obj === 'undefined') { return undefined; }
        return JSON.stringify(obj, toJsonReplacer, pretty ? '  ' : null);
    }

    return function(object) {
        return toJson(object, true);
    };
});
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/6QSZ7/)**.

---

<sub>* The downside is that your custom JSON filter will not benefit from further improvement/enhancement of Angular's `json` filter, so you'll have to re-define your's to incorporate changes. Of course, for such a basic and simple filter like this, one should'nt expect frequent or extensive changes, but that doesn't mean there aren't going to be any.</sub>

Comment: Excellent answer. “all we need to do is to create a custom filter that uses the exact same code with the sole difference that our `toJsonReplacer()` won't check for properties starting with `$`” That sounds a bit like “All you need to do is put this stone into hot water (along with some vegetables and stock), and bang, you got yourself soup!”

Comment: I didn't get your comment, but fell free to accet the answer if you fell like it ;)

Comment: @ExpertSystem FYI, the previous comment was referencing this old folktale: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone_Soup